# How to Click on one Checkbox that clicks all Checkboxes VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I want to be able to Click on one Checkbox on Excel VBA that is able to Click on 5 other Checkbox's. My scenario is I want to create a table that shows 5 types of Data, what I want to accomplish is to create a Checkbox that clicks all of these other checkbox's, and therefore loads all data without the user having to check all 5 of these other Checkbox's. I want this checkbox to also be ticked if the user has ticked all 5 other options, and when the user has clicked then unclicked this Checkbox, for all the options to unselect itself. Hope someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside the main check box click function add the oleobjects.object.value property

```
sub checkbox1_click()
activeworkbook.sheets(1).oleobjects("checkbox_2").object.value=true
end sub
```

you can add more check boxes in a similar way....so whenever the main check box (checkbox 1 ) is enabled all other checkboxes within the checkbox sub will also be enabled

Comment: similarly you can also reverse this.... by creating a sub that checks whether the five checkboxes values are true and change the value of the main check box